# Error On Button Click on Document.Ready() MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am working on ASP.NET MVC Code is given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {       
        $("#btnBookServiceCouponSection").click();

});</script>
```

here is my button code.

```
 <input type="button" id="btnBookServiceCouponSection"  style="min-width: 150px;"
                        value="Book a Service" onclick="NoCouponServiceAppointment()" />
```

When this button clicked then it call NoCouponServiceAppointment no Coupon code is given below.

```
this.NoCouponServiceAppointment = function () {

    RedirectToURL("/Appointment/SelectServices");
}
this.RedirectToURL = function (url) {
    document.location = url;
}
```

When this button click then it redirect to controller action method but before redirection it gives an error. this problem occurred only in chrome.
[image: Error Screen Shot]

When i click the button then above error occurred when i click OK of the error page then it working fine. please guide me why this error alert box occurred how i solve this problem thank you.

Comment: Use redirect in the javascript code like this. `$("#btnBookServiceCouponSection").click(function(){ document.href = "yourURL"; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem is Resolved.Code is given below.

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#btnBookServiceCouponSection").click(); }, 500);
```

Thank you every one for give me suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You are probably triggering `click` event before binding the `click` handler. You can bind the handler to click event as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {       
        $("#btnBookServiceCouponSection").click(function(){
           alert("clicked");
        });    
   });
</script>
```

Comment: how i solve this problem this is working fine when i debug the code i think some timeout issue?

Comment: Are you asking about the suggested solution? What is the problem?

Comment: i am asking how i solve this issue of error alertbox

Comment: @Ammar This must be caused by a `alert()` call, this is maybe because of your JS codes or ASP.NET JS codes

Comment: @ABFORCE when i debug the code then no error message shown then it working fine may be any timeout issue?

Comment: @Adil i try to change your code. but still giving error

Comment: @Ammar your provided info about the problem is not enough , please elaborate

Comment: The error would have some other reason, the given information does not seem to give any clue about the error